# iPhone 4 movies won't play in Quicktime, no sound in VLC

Tags: iphone, audio, video, quicktime

I've taken many videos with my iPhone 4, but when I uploaded them to my Macbook and try to  play them in Quicktime, they only show one frame and they don't play.

When I try to play with in VLC, they play but without sound and with improper orientation (portrait video is played in landscape mode).

These videos play just fine on the phone.  What do I need to do to get proper playback on my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same (or at least similar) issue: A video taken with my iPhone 4S (running the most up-to-date iOS 6) would not play in Quicktime player, but it DID play in the Finder preview, surprisingly. I finally figured out what I did wrong: I first downloaded all of my "Camera Roll" to my Mac in iPhoto, then exported the files from there to a Finder folder. However, I didn't pay attention that the default export file type is .jpg - which is obviously not the right one for a video. So I went into iPhoto again, selected the movie file, chose "Export" and then selected "Original" instead of "JPEG" from the "Kind:" pull-down menu. (Stupidly, iPhoto reverts back to "JPEG" the next time you open it - why? Also, why is there no easier way to download picture and movie files from the iPhone to the Mac than the route I just described? But this is besides the point of this discussion...)

Anyway, now the video plays in all the right ways as intended. - might be something to try?